# How can we know which part of waveform corresponds to which part of data?

Tags: c#, audio, waveform

I drew a waveform from a string, for example, see the image below where I drew a waveform from the string `tejibun`.

How can I tell which part of the waveform corresponds to each character? For example, in the image, how can I tell where is `j`, where is `i`, etc.?

[image]

Comment: What is the code you're using to draw the waveform?

Comment: I got a C library to change a string to the wave data array(byte[]). And from this byte data array i draw the waveform.

Comment: Maybe you could look into the source code of the method you're calling?

Comment: the problem is i drew the waveform from a byte[] array data. And i must define the position of letter in string on the waveform, like the image. Do you have any suggestion

Comment: Right, so maybe you can look into how the letters are being converted to bytes in that library. That would help you figure out how the waveform is being drawn.